# Can i use SSL encryption for my website when my hosting provider doesn't support it?

Tags: ssl, ssh, web, hosting

I've hosted my website using a free hosting space provider(Apache server) who makes me pay for `https://` support. Is there any possible way to implement SSL thereby making a secure data transaction between user and server. A simple Self-signed SSL certificate is fine. Is this possible? If so, how can i do it?
My hosting provider supports SSH support.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To get SSL encryption on your site you should generate CSR and install it on your desired server. So you cannot get SSL on your site if you are using a free hosting service and he is not supporting it. I would suggest to move on any paid hosting provider (it can be available from $2 per month). They usually support SSL encryption.